# Excell SUM minus numbers

Tags: worksheet-function

I am trying to add up specific groups of numbers (some negative) in a column, then get an average.

I've tried `=SUM($O8,$O9,$O10)/3` where `O8`, `O9`, and `O10` are negative numbers.

Other `SUM`s in the column are not all negative numbers but are a mix of positive and negative.

Any help how to do it would be brilliant.

---

It is a method of observing a market using the daily Open, High, Low, Close data I found in an old-ish book. I was curious enough to try and  unravel it. My initial application and findings are that it is way of the mark. But I like to get things right. I’m wondering if it is off the mark because of my inexperience with Excell or for another reason.

I interpreted the description (over 10 pages) as follows.

In Excell.

Raw data; Open (in D); High (in F); Low (in H); Close (in J)

The steps are;

1(a). =SUM($F7,$H7,$J7)/3*2-$F7 (in K) (Result)

1(b). =SUM($F7,$H7,$J7)/3*2-$H7 (in L) ((Result)

2. D; =$H8-$F7 (in O)
3. R; =$F8-$H7 (in P)
4. BH; =$F8-$F7 (in Q)
5. BU; =$H8-$H7 (in R)
6. D Average; =F7-AVERAGE($O6,$O7,$O8) (in S)
7. BU Average; =AVERAGE($R8,$R9,$R10)+H9 (in T)
8. BE; =SUM($H10,$K10,$S10,$T10)/4 (in U) ((Result)
9. R Average; =SUM($P8,$P9,$P10)/3+$H10 (in V)
10. BH Average; =SUM($Q8,$Q9,$Q10)/3+$F10 (in W)
11. SE; =SUM($F10,$L10,$V10,$W10)/4 (in X) (Result)

Comment: In case you have a mix of positive and negative numbers in a range and you wish to only SUM or AVERAGE based on negatives then use either SUMIF or AVERAGEIF functions.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You may want to add a little more detail on what you are trying to accomplish, or an example of the kind of data and result you want to see.

Comment: Do you mean you want to sum the absolute values of the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, it shouldn't make a difference whether the numbers are negative or positive. Just use the `AVERAGE` function:

`=AVERAGE(O8:O10)`

More info here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/average-function-047bac88-d466-426c-a32b-8f33eb960cf6

Comment: Thanks zeel for your help with posting a clearer message. =AVERAGE function looks like it will do what I want. I will check it in the morning to be sure and report back. goodnight.